# How to disable Replicated Data Population in Docusign programmatically?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

According to Docusign

> Data Population Scope is a great way to speed up the signing process by duplicating their data throughout the document automatically

I want to prevent this replication from happening programmatically.
Is there an argument I can pass to Text that would prevent this? Maybe something like:

```
Text(data_label="some_unique_label")
```

I tried doing

```
Text(name="some_unique_name")
```

This did not prevent data linking between other Text fields. According to the Docusign documentation I need to set a unique data label for each Field. However, I am not finding a `data_label` option for Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `tabLabel` parameter.

Data is populated between fields that have the same `tabLabel`, so if you make those unique, they won't share data.

Comment: Thank you very much @Drew